# SNS metrics using CFN

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-sns

I am trying to set up cloud watch alarm using SNS metrics by CFN scripts. I am not able to add the PhoneNumberDirect in the cfn code but on the console this metrics is there in the console while selecting manually.

[image]

```
      SNSAlarm:
    Type: AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm
    Properties:
      AlarmName: "OTP-Alarm"
      AlarmDescription: "Alarm for OTP failures"
      Namespace: "AWS/SNS"
      PhoneNumber: "PhoneNumberDirect"
      MetricName: "NumberOfNotificationsFailed"
      #Dimensions:
      #- Name: "PhoneNumber"
      # Value: "PhoneNumberDirect"
      Statistic: "Average"
      ComparisonOperator: "GreaterThanThreshold"
      Threshold: 20
      EvaluationPeriods: 1
```

Comment: What error do you get exactly?

Comment: Encountered unsupported property PhoneNumber - while trying to execute in the cloud formation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you tried using `Dimensions` as well but was not successful.

I was able to create a similar alarm on the same metric with the following CloudFormation template:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09

Resources:
  MyAlarm:
    Type: AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm
    Properties:
      ActionsEnabled: true
      AlarmActions:
        - 'arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:...:Default_CloudWatch_Alarms_Topic'
      AlarmDescription: Description
      AlarmName: Test Alarm
      ComparisonOperator: GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold
      DatapointsToAlarm: 1
      Dimensions:
        - Name: PhoneNumber
          Value: PhoneNumberDirect
      MetricName: NumberOfNotificationsFailed
      Namespace: AWS/SNS
      Period: 300
      Statistic: Sum
      Threshold: 1
      TreatMissingData: missing
      EvaluationPeriods: 1
```

Feel free to play around with this to get your desired output.